# Django error: python manage.py dumpdata auth.User --indent 4 > users.json

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run the following:

**python manage.py dumpdata auth.User --indent 4 > users.json**

**I get this error:**

```
/Users/user/Documents/workspace/example/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py:395:

RuntimeWarning: Unable to load plugin selenium_fixtures 
= noseselenium.plugins:SeleniumFixturesPlugin: cannot import name AdminMediaHandler
  RuntimeWarning)
```

I have Selenium and nose installed. So how can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance?

Comment: comment out selenium and nose from `INSTALLED_APPS` and try

Comment: some dependencies. Hard to tell what without seeing the code :)